# I am facing problems in sql query. ORDER By or UNION make error

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

In a table occasions is stored with start_date, end_date and with sort_order and other fields.

I am working on a **django-rest-framework(rest-api)**, so that i am using custom **postgres** query for this.

My need is sorting these results acc. to

1. sort categories
2. top 6 upcoming occasions acc. date range (occasion_start_date, Occasion_end_date)
3. rest other occasion list acc. to sort order or name

for this i make a query which is not working:

[sql query which gives error because orderby clause is not used with UNION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFNiB.png)

[this query return results but upcoming occasion not on top :-(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfraQ.png)

My First query is:

```
SELECT * FROM public.product_productcategory WHERE is_active=True and occasion_end_date > now() and occasion_start_date > now()
UNION 
SELECT * FROM public.product_productcategory WHERE is_active=True  
ORDER BY sort_order, name asc
```

this query not give my exact result

```
SELECT * FROM public.product_productcategory WHERE is_active=True and occasion_end_date > now() and occasion_start_date > now() ORDER BY occasion_start_date asc
UNION 
SELECT * FROM public.product_productcategory WHERE is_active=True  ORDER BY sort_order, name asc
```

This gives error.

Comment: You should past your query as text into your question.

Comment: @Suresh in your 2nd image, I saw it's on top: you ORDER BY  occasion_start_date first, and that's it: min occasion_start_date = 2016-06-16 on top? What else do you want?

Comment: @PhamX.Bach i want upcoming occasions are coming first then rest of occasions are coming acc. to sort_order or name

Comment: It seems that I don't understand your intention. Could you please show your expected output (7 first rows you want). Maybe only ID, like: 17 - 16 - 14 - 13 - 21 - 23 - 18 - 19 .... ?

Comment: i want upcoming occasion means occasions which start_date is greater then current date time is coming first then rest of occasion come below acc. to sort order of name

Comment: The order by of the first UNION part is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to follow your query.  However, `order by` only works as the last clause in a `union`/`union all` query.  So, you might intend:

```
select . . . from . . . where . . .
union
select . . . from . . . where . . .
order by sort_order, name;
```

Also, you should use `union all`, unless you intend to remove duplicates in the result set.

Comment: i already use this but this not gives my axact results.

upcoming occasions not coming on top using this query. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

I am assuming that occasionname is unique and primarykey of product_productcategory table

```
 SELECT top 6 * into #Temp FROM public.product_productcategory WHERE is_active=True and occasion_end_date > now() 
and occasion_start_date > now() order by sort_order, name;

 Select * from #Temp
 union 
 Select * from  public.product_productcategory P
 left join #Temp1 t1
 on p1.occasionname= t1.occasionname
 where t1.occasionname is null
 order by sort_order, name;
```

please Reply...........

Comment: There is no `TOP` in Postgres. And `#Temp` is an invalid identifier. And even if that did work, it won't help because the  `select * from #Temp` still produces an un-ordered result. The fact that the `select` for the `insert` has an `order by` doesn't change that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are after, but maybe something like:

```
select *
from (
  SELECT *, 
         case 
           when and occasion_end_date > now() and occasion_start_date > now()
             then row_number() over (order by occasion_end_date desc) as rn
           else null
         end as rn
  FROM public.product_productcategory 
  WHERE is_active 
) t
where rn <= 6 or rn is null -- only pick the first 6
order by rn nulls last, sort_order, name
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution with the help of one of my senior

```
SELECT *,
       case 
         when occasion_start_date > now() or now() < occasion_end_date then 1 
         else 2 
       end as sort_column 
FROM public.product_productcategory 
WHERE is_active=True 
order by sort_column,occasion_start_date desc
```

Comment: Thanks all guys, you(stackoverflow) rocks :-)